Как проверить номер телефона на регистрацию в WhatsApp?
Гытаюсь написать код, который не использует API. Код должен проверять, зарегистрирован ли номер телефона, который вводит пользователь, в WhatsApp.
Я попытался написать код, и вот что у меня получилось. Когда вы вводите номер, зарегистрированный в WhatsApp, в консоли отображается, что номер не зарегистрирован
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import carrier

def is_whatsapp_number(phone_number):
    try:
        phone_number = phonenumbers.parse(phone_number)
        if phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phone_number):
            service_provider = carrier.name_for_number(phone_number, lang="EN")
            if "WhatsApp" in service_provider:
                return "YES"
            else:
                return "NO"
        else:
            return "Invalid phone number"
    except phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException:
        return "Invalid phone number"

phone_number = input("Enter the phone number: ")
result = is_whatsapp_number(phone_number)
print(result)


carrier.name_for_number возвращает имя оператора, а не строку, которая содержит WhatsApp, смотрите документацию

а что возвращает наличие WhatsApp? в документации не нашел

Найти библиотеку, которая может, или воспользоваться этим ответом так-что вопрос дубликат получается.

я видел этот вопрос, но ничего от туда мне не помогло
